# JavaFX Won't load/find profiles

Tags: java, javafx

I've read other topics relating to this and I still can't figure it out.

My project tree:

[image]

I'm having issues loading. I've tried:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

With variations of main/sample.fxml, ../sample.fxml, etc

Getting the same error everytime:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: profiles (The system cannot find the file specified)`

I've tried this:

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

and it returns:

```
file:/C:/Users/pcname/git/javafx-project/main/sample.fxml
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "profiles" refer to? Is that the entire error message or is there more? Is it possible that the problem is not loading sample.fxml, but something that sample.fxml refers to?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of Eclipse, the project files can be out of sync with the file system. Try right clicking on the project -> Refresh (or press F5) and then try running.